# Finding polynomial coefficients returns Tag Plus is Protected

Tags: warning-messages, polynomials, coefficients

I'm trying to find the coefficients of a polynomial $P(x)$. Please see following equation.

$$P(x+2)+P(x-2)=2x+8$$

```
CoefficientList[P(x+2)+P(x-2)=2x+8,P(x)]
```

However it returns an error.

```
Set::write: Tag Plus in P(-2+x)+P(2+x) is Protected.
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is P(x+2)? The input of `CoefficientList` should be a polynomial, not an equation.

Comment: @DanielHuber Sorry - which function should be used for this equation? I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what you want to do. If  P(..) is a function, it should be written P[..].  Note, equations are solved using `Solve`or `Reduce`, not `Coefficient List`

Comment: @DanielHuber I'm trying to find total of coefficents of P(x) at equation given. Updated question accordingly. Sorry again, I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: Edited it again, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand.  Are you searching a polynomial P[x] so that P[x+2]+P[x-2] == 2x+8

Comment: @DanielHuber Yes, that is correct. I'm looking for the coefficents of that polynomial. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest approach is to use `SolveAlways`:

```
p[x_] = a x + b;
SolveAlways[p[x + 2] + p[x - 2] == 2 x + 8, x]
(* {{a -> 1, b -> 4}} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

The reason you get the error message is that you are using the single equals sign, which is an assignment operator.  The double equals sign (==) is used for arithmetic comparisons.

In addition to the single equals (call `Set`), there is a `SetDelayed` (:=) which is used to define functions.  For example, a polynomial could be defined like this

```
Clear[a,b,x,p]

p[x_] := a*x + b
```

And the comparison could be made like this

```
p[x+2] + p[x-2] == 2*x + 8
```

The comparison can be used with `Resolve` and `ForAll` like this

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, p[x + 2] + p[x - 2] == 2*x + 8], {a, b}]
```

to get the result

```
a == 1 && b == 4
```

As you will discover, there are many other ways of getting this same result in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that `P` is of degree 1, then

```
P[x_] := a*x + b
```

The known equation then becomes

```
eqn = P[x + 2] + P[x - 2] == 2 x + 8 // Expand

(* 2 b + 2 a x == 8 + 2 x *)
```

Equating the coefficients from each side

```
eqns = Thread[CoefficientList[#, x] & /@ eqn]

(* {2 b == 8, 2 a == 2} *)
```

Solving these equations for `a` and `b`

```
sol = Solve[eqns, {a, b}]

(* {{a -> 1, b -> 4}} *)
```

`P` is then

```
P2[x_] = P[x] /. sol[[1]]

(* 4 + x *)
```

Verifying,

```
P2[x + 2] + P2[x - 2]

(* 8 + 2 x *)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the highest order of the right hand side is 1, P must be a linear polynomial. This gives the following equation that must be correct for all values of x:

```
p[x_]= c0 + c1 x;
eq= ForAll[x, p[x+2]+ p[x-2] == 2x +8];
```

To solve this you use `Reduce`. This is a more complex version of `Solve` that can deal e.g. with the `ForAll` we are using:

```
Reduce[eq, {c0, c1}]
(*c0 == 4 && c1 == 1*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RSolve[P[x + 2] + P[x - 2] == 2 x + 8, P, x]
```

If P[x] is a polynomial then $c_1=c_2=c_3=c_4=0$